# IPE and MiKTex problem - win7

Tags: miktex, windows, ipe, cygwin

It's my first experience with **LaTex** in  windows, I'm used to using a macbook and I can handle things well.

As a first approach I thought about using **[MiKTeX 2.9](https://miktex.org/2.9/setup)** and my dear **[TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/)**

To make some graphs I'm using **[IPE 7.2.7](http://ipe.otfried.org/)**, which I normally use on a macbook without any problem.

During the preparation of a chart I found a problem, when I'm going to insert a mathematical text, for exaple if insert `\rho`.

I can not solve this, could you give me a hand?

[image]
[image]

Comment: most frequent issue in cases like this is knowledge of paths from IPE manual **"You will want to either add the "bin" subdirectory to your path, or
add a shortcut to Ipe to your desktop or your start menu. Ipe requires a LaTeX installation including 'pdflatex'.  Make sure that 'pdflatex' is on your path!"** TeXstudio will expect those steps have been done. SO at start button type in cmd to get a command prompt then enter at> **where /r c: ipe.exe** (and **where /r c: pdfLaTeX.exe**) finaly enter>  path (check the IPE bin and MiKTeX bin identified in the first 2 steps are included in the path)

Comment: are you really trying to run amstex?

Comment: @Ulrike No. It's a mistake. I'll follow the suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: with TeXstudio MiKTeX and ipe versions as give and all on path  then inside ipe entering at text prompt $\rho$ I get the rho symbol; without any error. Any non valid tex such as omitting the $ will give me an expected error such as **! Extra }, or forgotten $.**

Comment: @KJO I solved by installing TexLive and inserting the system PATHs. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attempt to insert a tex object or open an ipe file without a valid pdfLaTeX.exe on the system or user **path** you will automatically get the error message as shown in the upper screen shot. Once a TeX engine is in place **on the path** IPE will automatically use it and opening an .ipe or adding any piece of TeX will automatically be compiled as in the lower screen shot.

[image]